# Typecasting C pointers to access raw memory

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying understand how one can access more of memory by typecasting.  From watching this video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldN5i6MMquM

It sounds like I can typecast a pointer to uint16_t to access 2 parts of a 8 bit addressed memory array.  I can't seem to access more than 8 bits and I'm not sure how to write it in c in order to be able to access two bytes instead of one.  I started out with something like below

```
    uint8_t *memory = (uint8_t*) malloc(8);
    memory[0] = 5;
    memory[1] = 21;
    memory[2] = 4;
    memory[3] = 9;
    memory[4] = 23;
    memory[5] = 66;
    memory[6] = 211;
    memory[7] = 46;
```

Comment: [Don't ever cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: "not sure what to do from there"... Well, what *do* you want to do? What is the purpose of the `memory` "array"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: And note that type-casting has nothing to do with accessing memory. You can allocate memory for any purpose and assign the pointer returned by `malloc` to any kind of pointer.

Comment: From what I understand, a value can be stored across memory so that it takes up several address.  I want to be able to access more than just the one byte as the video mentions.  I'm just not sure how that is able to be implemented

Comment: The video shows you how to cast the `uint8_t *` to  a `uint16_t *`. What is it you aren't understanding?

Comment: In my program I can not access more than 8 bits even though I have type casted to uint16_t*.  I was hoping to see it fleshed out more in code vs theory

Comment: "*... even though I have type casted to uint16_t.*" You do not show us this part of your program.

Comment: I edited the text but I'll try to add more when I get to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have definitions of all uintXX_t types and an array of bytes like this

```
uint8_t bytes[8]; 
uint32_t *p3 = (uint32_t *)&bytes[4];
uint8_t *p = bytes;
uint16_t *p1 = (uint16_t *)bytes;
uint32_t *p2 = (uint32_t *)bytes;

                     | uint32_t *p3: accesses a 32bit value starting at bytes[4]
                     v
 bytes: [0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]
         ^
         | uint8_t *p: can access bytes[0] 
         ^
         | uint16_t *p1: can access 16bits (2 bytes) [0][1]
         ^ 
         | uint32_t *p2: can access 32bits (4 bytes) [0][1][2][3]
```

and so on.
You can also define a struct like this:

```
struct A { uint8_t x, uint16_t y; };
struct A *ps = (struct A *)bytes;
```

Then ps will 'see' your bytes array as a struct of type A and you can access the values like this:

```
 uint8_t x = ps->x; // bytes: [0]
 uint16_t y = ps->y; // bytes: [1][2]
```

After you understand this, read up on structure member alignment :)

Comment: Thank you! Explanation is helpful.  If I wanted to see the value of p1, I would just do this?

printf("%d", *p2);

And I would get the value of both bytes combined?

Comment: %d requires an integer (typically 32bits) on the stack - p2 is uint32, so you can use it. If you want the unsigned value use %u instead of %d.

Answer (score 0):

In the video you have mentioned, he is not really allocating memory.
All that is being explained that if the pointer type is `uint8_t`, the pointer points to a memory location 8 bits long. 

If the pointer is now type casted to point to a `unit16_t`, it now points to a memory location 16 bits long. That is equivalent to two 8 bit locations.

It does not conjure more memory out of your memory. It simply addresses a larger range of addresses than before.

Comment: Right I know that.  The problem is that I wanted to see it in practice as I can't seem to implement in code properly. When I do it, I only can access 8 bits even though I've typecasted to 16

Answer (score 0):

Just define another 16 bit pointer, assign it to the same address

```
  uint16_t* memory16 = (uint16_t*)memory;
```

Now you can look at each two 8 bit elements of your memory, like one 16 bit ellement

```
  for(i = 0; i< 4; ++i)
      printf("%d  ", memory16[i]);
```

and feel the difference

```
 for( i = 0; i< 8; ++i)
     printf("%d  ", memory[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you Dabo.  That's helpful.  I'll have to mess with that when I get back from work.